# Sas Add-in for Microsoft office, installation error in office 365 / windows10 : Culture is not supported

Tags: installation, sas, windows-10, excel-addins

Migrating to Windows 10 on a desktop and doing a clean install of SAS V94 SAS_Add-In_for_Microsoft_Office_Independent_Installer.

After launching Excell I got the following error message :

> ### Exception information
>
> Exception type:  System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
>   Message:         Culture is not supported.
>   Parameter name: culture 3072 (0x0c00) is an invalid culture identifier.
>
> Source:          mscorlib
>   Target Site:     InitializeFromCultureId
>
> Stack Trace:
>     at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InitializeFromCultureId(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
>     at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
>
> at SAS.OfficeAddin.Global.SwitchThreadUICulture(Object app)
>
> at SAS.OfficeAddin.Connect.CreateAddIn()
>
> at SAS.ExcelAddIn.VstoExcelAddIn.CreateAddIn()
>
> ### Configuration Details
>
> SAS Software :
>
> SAS Add-In for Microsoft Office version: 8.0 (8.0.0.1995) (32-bit)
>    SAS System version: 9405.100.22960.39165
>    SAS System Command: c:\sas\v94\sasfoundation\9.4\sas.exe -config c:\sas\v94\sasfoundation\9.4\sasv9.cfg -objectserver -nologo -noterminal -noprngetlist
>    SAS Shared Files: C:\sas\v94\x86
>    JMP Installation:
>
> Operating System :
>
> Name: Unknown
>    Version: 10.0.0.17763
>    Service pack: No Service Pack Installed
>    .NET Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.42000 (no service pack)
>
> Add-In for Microsoft Office 8.0 :
>
> Installed location: C:\sas\v94\x86\SASAddInforMicrosoftOffice\8\
>    Service pack level: 8.0
>    Installed languages: English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This installation error seems to be caused by the differences in culture setting between Windows 10 and office 365.

Compare the Windows 10 languages : Control Panel, Region, Language preferences
With Office 365 : Open e.g. Excel, File, Options, Language, Choose Editing Languages

Adding a missing language to Excell solved the installation problem.
After that Sas continued and completed the installation succesfully.

I am not completely sure this is the exact cause.  But at least it solved the problem.